# Recommended approach for presenting formatted text in Android?

Tags: html, android, webview, textview

I am developing an application that will provide instructions to making a product.  The text will have bullets and/or numbered steps as well regular text paragraphs.  I may have headings for various sections.  The text will be placed into a scrollable TexView.

I was originally planning on loading the text from a resource text file and then applying formatting via xml.  However, I just learned about WebView and the ability to load local html files.  I could easily format the text in html and load it into a WebView for the various activities.

My question is, is there a performance issue with using WebView vs. TextView?  Are there other ways to easily format text for a TextView?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WebView` definitely takes longer to load the first time into your process. It also is not designed to go in a `ScrollView`, since it scrolls itself. OTOH, you get excellent HTML support.

`TextView` can display limited HTML, converted into a `SpannedString` via `Html.fromHtml()`. [Here is a blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) where I list the HTML tags supported by the Android 2.1 edition of `fromHtml()`. Note that these are undocumented, and so the roster of tags may be different in other Android releases.