# Displaying large amouts of text: ViewPager vs ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, textview, android-viewpager

I have a large reference book in a SQLite database. (The text is stored in sentences or paragraphs for easier searchability in the future.)

Currently, the user can select any chapter in the book, and that chapter is displayed in a TextView in a ScrollView. This works fine for the current chapter, but I would like to be able to continue scrolling to the next or previous chapter. I could just reload the TextView with the next chapter, but I am guessing that there would be a delay and the transition would not be very smooth.

I've considered options such as a [WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824674/android-display-lots-of-text), stacked [FrameLayouts](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/), and [ViewFlippers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869180/how-to-use-view-flipper-with-three-layouts), but I think I have narrowed it down to using either a ListView or a ViewPager. I want to scroll indefinitely in either direction through the short chapters while still being light on resources (i.e., recycling views).

Before I invest a lot of time in figuring out how to use one method, is there an obvious best choice or factors I should consider?

Comment: I'd prefer to read a book "page by page", so a ViewPager seems a better choice, to me. Others might like a vertical scrolling.

Comment: I'm leaning that way myself not because I personally prefer it, but because I'm not sure how I would implement scrolling indefinitely backwards with a ListView. I wasn't very clear in my question, but I was referring to whether or not there are technical factors that would make one choice better than the other.

Comment: Nope... personal taste. If you're asking which is the **easier way** to implement, then it's the ListView